# C#: Repository pattern, is there a standard interface or should i cook my own?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern

I have been doing a bit of research with the repository pattern and I have been rolling my own Interfaces for the repository.

I was wondering if there is a standard interface that I can implement that has Find methods and things like that?

And I presume I need to implement my own interface as well for thing like GetProduct, GetProducts etc?

I was also putting everything in one repository but this seems to be getting quite large, I presume I should separate them to difference repositories?  I presume separate them by what they do i.e. Security, Products, Sales etc?

I do seem to remember seeing a standard type Repository interface which I think each class implements but I can't seem to find any reference to it.

Comment: i've been messing with the .tt files that come with l2s and EF - it's a good start and also look at the POCO starterkit, sample code from prism and devforce

Comment: What ORM are you using? NHibernate, EF, Linq2Sql?

Comment: Its interesting to me that a comments to a question about a pattern that is supposed to abstract away data access methods contain questions about which data access method you are using.  A repository shouldn't change or be dependent upon which ORM you are using.

Comment: It is the standard repository pattern i want to implement, it shouldn't depend on any type of data access. Martin fowler has a good explanation about this. But if its really important i am using EF

Comment: Now that I understand the distinction between DDD and PoEAA repository patterns a bit better, I realize this is a pretty high-quality question, so +1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are by chance talking about domain-driven design repositories (which I think you must not be given the way you talk about them), the code for [Steve Bohlen's DDD presentation](http://unhandled-exceptions.com/blog/index.php/2010/11/27/dc-altnet-presentationthats-a-wrap/) gives a standard repository interface. I wouldn't say it's used widely (i.e. *is standard*), but it does adhere to the DDD guidelines pretty closely (i.e. *follows standards*).

If you are talking about the more general concept of a data-access layer, I would be sure not to call that a repository because of the confusion with the DDD concept, and perhaps conform to the same method names etc. of stuff like the Entity Framework's [`ObjectContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.aspx) class, or even just `ICollection<T>` or `IDictionary<TKey, T>` if appropriate.

Comment: Yes i am talking about the repository pattern (martin fowler), which is a layer that sits between dataaccess and the client

Comment: Oh, so you are talking about the PoEAA repository pattern (intermediate between DAL and domain), not the DDD repository pattern (lives in the domain). In that case my latter paragraph applies.

Answer (score 0):

By following related question links, I found this interesting blog post: [Repository or DAO?: Repository](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/09/repository-or-dao-repository.html).

It says that the appropriate interface to couple to for a *Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture* repository is

```
public interface IRepository<T> : ICollection<T>, IQueryable<T> { }
```